# In "The Crucible" how did the girls turn cold?

Tags: the-crucible

*The Crucible* (1953) is a play by Arthur Miller about the Salem Witch Trials. In the play the girls, led by Abigail, cry spirits and witch on the villagers. When they do so they go into a kind of trance and go ice cold and sometimes faint, in a way possessed by God to root out the devil's workers.

However, they are faking. It's their way of getting out of trouble and eventually to get rid of people that they don't like.

Nonetheless, they turn icy cold.

One of the girls, Mary, admits they were faking. She is asked to prove it:

> HATHORNE: And yet, when people accused of witchery confronted you in court, you would faint, saying their spirits came out of their bodies and choked you….
>   MARY: That were pretense, sir.
>   HAWTHORNE: Then can you pretend to faint now?

She cannot -- she doesn't *fail*, she just does not try.

> PARRIS: Why not? Now there are no spirits attacking you, for none in this room is accused of witchcraft. So let you turn yourself cold now, let you pretend you are attacked now, let you faint. Faint!

She says she has no sense of it, she cannot pretend.

Mere seconds later, Abigail claims she sees spirits, and goes cold.

> HATHORNE: (Touching Abigail’s hand.) She is cold, your Honor, touch her!

So my question is, how do the girls pretend to go cold? For never once are we the audience led to believe there actually are spirits in Salem. I'm not aware of the answer being in the play, but as this text is regularly studied by schools I'm sure there are scores of critics.

If they are faking, is there any suggestion of how they go cold?

Granted, if it's not in the play any answer is speculation, but coming from a critic it would be *accepted* speculation I suppose ...

Does anyone know of any theories behind this ability to go cold, or if it is possible in reality even, short of there actually being spirits in Salem?

Comment: I'd guess it's through the power of suggestion, not on the girls' part, but it's Hathorne who's expecting Abigail to be cold to the touch, so she is _to him_.

Comment: How do you know her hands were not already cold?  Some people with poor circulation, have cold hands.  Did they ever check Abigail at other times to see if her hands were cold?

Comment: An emotional state could also trigger basic reactions like restricting blood flow to the limbs, making them cold.

Comment: Hathorne has a vested interest in not looking foolish. She says she's cold and he challenges his fellow judge to agree. On top of that she's visibly shivering.

Comment: I thought of Oldcat's comment, but figured to just turn that on and off would be a bit much to be able to do. I also thought of Zoredache's comment but while they don't check her hands, she had an affair with Proctor and IIRC has her hands all over him a couple of times -- he would have noticed, especially as he's the man trying to prove they're faking. SQB and Richard, I think you guys have got it, though I won't say I don't feel a fool for not thinking of that myself: I was thinking of stupid ways (like rubbing your forehead on a carpet to get a temperature) instead of the simplest.

Comment: Shouldn’t this belong on [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.staciexchange.com)?

Comment: @InventPalooza too old to migrate. (older than 6 months)

Comment: @InventPalooza - No, because the presence of (supposedly) supernatural elements isn't conclusively shown to be non-supernatural. It's left ambiguous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my mind there are four plausible reasons why Danforth might state that Abigail's hand is cold:

1) **Her hands might be *naturally* cool to the touch**. Out of universe, Abigail Williams was a [known epileptic](http://salem.lib.virginia.edu/people?group.num=G07&mbio.num=mb33) and was undergoing a regime of fasting. Both of these would have contributed to poor circulation and seizures (which themselves are known to cause the sort of [shivering and hallucinations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC531654/) consistent with what we see in the play).

---

2) She may simply have had her **hands pressed against the cold bench**.

> **DANFORTH:** *Sit you down, children.* (Silently they sit.)

---

3) **Hathorne is intentionally lying.** He has a vested interest in not looking foolish and  although he challenges the other judges to feel her hands, none of them appear to actually do so.

---

4) **Hathorne is experiencing a psychosomatic response.** He's already stated that he doesn't want to accuse her of lying so when she shivers and tells him that she feels cold, he's accepts this at face value even if the evidence doesn't bear it out.

> **DANFORTH:** (He weakens.) **Child, I do not mistrust you…**

Comment: Did you forget you never wrote an answer? ;) These answers are great -- I was too caught up in the conspiracy to see these: number 2 is quite similar to how I used to rub my forehead on the carpet so I didn't have to go to school :D The first point scares me though: maybe she really DID see all those spirits :) Anyway, even better in answer form than in comments, and now I can accept it.

Comment: @MacCooper - Guilty as charged. I forgot to answer it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think the reason is more complicated than that. When people are in groups, they tend to act differently. I guess it's a kind of "group adrenaline". For example, there are plenty groups of teenagers that would go in Walmart and mess around, but if it was just one teenager, it would be unlikely for them to do. When Abigail is in the group, all of their energy combines in a way and they act different than they normally would.

When Abigail is singled out, it's not that she isn't trying, it's simply that she doesn't have that group adrenaline to back her up and give her the mentality to do so. That's why when she goes back to the group, she is able to "see a spirit" and therefore, she faints.

Her hands are probably either naturally cold, or they were cold because she was nervous. But to be honest, I think that's a minor detail and the group adrenaline is the point in this story. Groups just make bad decisions. But they have to be in groups to have the courage to do so.